# Change ownership of dir to user when running program in sudo

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, directory, permissions

I have a program that I need to run with `sudo`. I create a directory using [mkdir](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir), but this directory has owner and group set to root. That makes sense since I am using `sudo`. I would like to change the owner and group to the normal user, but I'm not sure how to do that. I thought running `system("chown $USER:$USER /directory/")` would work, but I suppose since I am in sudo it will just set to root. I was looking into using [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/3/chown), but I wasn't sure how I was supposed to get the owner and group id. Also it would be good for it to be portable, so I don't want to just hardcode a user/group id.

Comment: When you do `sudo`, you have this variable `$SUDO_USER` in your sudo session.

Comment: That works. Thanks @Philippe

Answer (score 3):

You're mostly on the right path already, chown is the command you're looking for here.

You can string the two commands to make and then own the directory together using a semicolon.

sudo mkdir test ; sudo chown $USER:$USER test

I've tested this on ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04 as that's your tag. The $USER variable resolves to the user that you originally logged in as, not root, as long as you're using it at the beginning of your command like the above. Note that you need to call sudo again when doing the chown portion, the ; ends the sudo elevation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I linked the wrong thing for mkdir. I'm using the function mkdir(const char *, mode_t) (link updated in question). So I tried using the mkdir() function and then running `system("sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/user/Desktop/data//p/"). But when I do ls -lh, I see the user and group as root.

Comment: Actually, turns out @Philippe was right about using $SUDO_USER

Answer (score 1):

The coreutils package includes an useful little command, [`install`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html), you can use instead of `mkdir` in a sudo context.  For example,

```
sudo install -o USER -g GROUP -m MODE -d DIRECTORY
```

where `USER` is the user to own the directory `DIRECTORY`, `GROUP` is the group to own the directory, and `MODE` is the access mode (like `chmod`) to the directory.

Because `system(COMMAND)` and `popen(COMMAND,...)` actually run `/bin/sh` with `-c` and `COMMAND` as parameters, you can use the form

```
sudo install -o $(id -u) -g $(id -g) -m u=rwx,g=r-x,o=x DIRECTORY
```

where the shell replaces the user and group names (or rather, numbers, since I'm not using the `-n` option) before executing sudo.  (The `id` command is also included in coreutils, so you can definitely expect both `install` and `id` to be available on all full-blown Linux machines; and even on most embedded systems.  It is what all package managers et cetera use to install files, you see.)

Above, I used the mode `u=rwx,g=r-x,o=x` (equivalently, `0751`) as an example; it sets the mode to `rwxr-x--x`, i.e. grants access to everybody, with owner user and group being able to list the directory contents, and only the owner user being able to create new files or directories in it.